# symfony2 service not registering dependencies

Tags: symfony, service, dependencies

I'm trying to create a service to persist/flush data  from a json feed to doctrine

The services dependencies are:

- Doctrine EntityManager
- The Api that pulls the Data

My Service Config:

```
services:
    fantasyapi:
        class:        FantasyDataAPI\Client
        arguments:    ["%fantasyapi.key%"]
    stadium_parser:
        class:        FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager\StadiumParser
        arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@fantasyapi"]
```

My Service:

```
<?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FantasyDataAPI\Client;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class StadiumParser {
    /**
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    private  $em;
    /**
     * @var Client $client
     */
    private $client;

    public function __constuct( EntityManager $em, Client $client) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public Function parseData(){
        $stadiumData = $this->client->Stadiums();
        //var_dump($stadiumData);
        //get the Repo
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');

        $log = array();

        foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
            // Get the current stadium in the list
            $criteria = array( 'stadiumID' => $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium = $repo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $currentStadium) {
                $currentStadium = new Stadium(); //no stadium with the StadiumID exists so create a new stadium

                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Added Stadium',
                    'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                    'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            } else {
                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Updated '.$logTitle,
                    'itemID'   => $stadium['PlayerID'],
                    'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            }
            $currentStadium->setStadiumID( $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            $currentStadium->setName( $stadium['Name'] );
            $currentStadium->setCity( $stadium['City'] );
            $currentStadium->setState( $stadium['State'] );
            $currentStadium->setCountry( $stadium['Country'] );
            $currentStadium->setCapacity( $stadium['Capacity'] );
            $currentStadium->setPlayingSurface( $stadium['PlayingSurface'] );
            $this->em->persist( $currentStadium );
        }
        $this->em->flush();
        return $log;
    }
```

I call this service from my controller:

```
public function StadiumServiceTestAction(){
        $parser = $this->container->get('stadium_parser');
        $log = $parser->parseData();
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('log' => $log));

    }
```

When i call
`$stadiumData = $this->client->Stadiums();`

i get the following error: `Call to a member function Stadiums() on a non-object`

If i do a `var_dump($this);` right at the beginning of my method i get:

```
object(FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager\StadiumParser)[5133] 
private 'em' => null 
private 'client' => null
```

Why aren't the dependencies getting injected?
If I do php `app/console container:debug` my service is listed

```
[container] Information for service stadium_parser
Service Id       stadium_parser
Class            FantasyPro\DataBundle\DataManager\StadiumParser
Tags             -
Scope            container
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Required File    -
```

I've performed php `app/console cache:clear --env=dev` also but to no avail

Comment: Do you actually use your `Stadium $stadium` which is in the constructor of the `StadiumParser` class? You pass a string there in the service definition - `::DataBundle.Entity.Stadium` - but you expect to get a `Stadium` entity (which is wrong approach anyway).

Comment: it checks the to see if the entry exists in the database, if not it creates a new Stadium Entity, adds the data and persits/flushes the new entity to the database.
What is the correct way to pass the Stadium Entity?

Comment: if i remove the stadium entity completely from the service and constructor i still get $em and $client as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the params are suppose to be injected in the costructor you may consider renaming the method `__constuct` to `__construct`.

Comment: Bingo, can't believe i missed that typo, been staring at it for too long!

Comment: Yes thats the next step, searching and reading now on PHPUnit and how to test outside of controllers and mocking my data, So much to learn!!!